# Finding X from Exponential Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

$$2^x \cdot 4^{1-x}= 8^{-x}$$

I wrote all the base numbers as a power of 2 but I'm not sure what to do after.

Comment: Do you mean $2^x\cdot 4^{1-x}=8^{-x}$?

Comment: If all of the bases are the same, add the exponents on the left hand side and then equate that with the exponent on the right hand side.

Answer (score 4):

$$2^x \cdot 4^{1-x}= 8^{-x}$$
$$\implies 2^x\cdot (2^2)^{1-x}=(2^3)^{-x}$$
$$\implies2^x\cdot 2^{2-2x}=2^{-3x}$$
$$\implies 2^{x+2-2x}=2^{-3x}$$
$$\implies 2^{2-x}=2^{-3x}$$
comparing both side we have,
$$2-x=-3x$$
$$\implies -2x=2$$
$$\implies x=-1$$

Comment: Two flaws: 1) "comparing both sides" is not a solid argument for why $2^a=2^b\,\Rightarrow\, a=b$. 2) If you use "implies" one-direction arrows instead of "iff", i.e. $\iff$, you must check if the final solutions work. There is nothing at all brilliant about this answer either, and the upvotes are confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Using $2^x\cdot 4^{1-x}=8^{-x}$ from the comments, write everything as a power of two: $2^x\cdot (2^2)^{1-x}=(2^3)^{-x}$, and then use the rules of exponents. You need these: $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ and $a^ma^n=a^{m+n}$.

Once you have simplified the expression to something like $2^a=2^b$, you can take log base 2 to get $a=b$, and then solve for $x$.

Comment: Another way to look at it is $2^x$ is a strictly increasing function (see [this picture](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP57631dg706gc5hah20890000273ch25h93i74f5d?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=28&w=325.&h=162.&cdf=RangeControl)), so $2^a=2^b$ is only possible if $a=b$.

Answer (score -2):

If you are referring to $2^x * 4^{1-x} = 8^{-x}$ then here are the steps

$2^x * 4^{1-x} = 8^{-x}$

$2^x * 4^1 4^{-x} = 8^{-x}$

$2^x * 4\frac{1}{4^{x}} = \frac{1}{8^{x}}$

$4=\frac{4^x}{8^x 2^x}$

$4={\frac{1}{4}}^x$

$log_{\frac{1}{4}}(4)=x$

$x=-1$

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could be (I hope !) amazed to know that there is another solution in the complex domain but this is off-topic. Cheers.